# Equivalent of `ping -o` on Linux

Tags: linux, ping

Apparently MacOs's `ping` has a `-o` option which means "return once the first successful response is received" or something like that. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6119327/4561887.

Is there an equivalent on Linux Ubuntu? How can we best achieve the same result?

My version is `ping utility, iputils-s20161105`, as returned by `ping -V`.

Update: I found the MacOs documentation here: https://ss64.com/osx/ping.html

> ```
> -o         Exit successfully after receiving one reply packet.
> ```

Comment: This looks potentially promising: https://serverfault.com/a/42382/357116

Comment: As does this: https://serverfault.com/a/545408/357116

Comment: @A.B, no, after testing `fping`, I can say the following: `fping 192.168.0.1` behaves like `ping -c 4 -W 1 192.168.0.1` when the network is down, and like `ping -c 1 192.168.0.1` when the network is up.  `fping` returns immediately if the network is up, and tries 4 times (1 initial try plus 3 retries, with a 1 second timeout after each attempt) if the network is down, returning after 4 timeouts = 4 sec total. `ping -o` would return immediately if the network is up, but loop forever _until the network comes up_, then return, if the network was down.

Comment: Did you read the man page?

Comment: @symcbean, which man page? The man page for Linux's `ping`, MacOS's `ping`, or `fping`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my own study plus reviewing the two other answers here, I have concluded: **there is no equivalent on Linux to the `ping -o` command which exists on MacOS.** Neither `ping -c 1` *nor* `fping` have the same behavior. **The best you can do is emulate its behavior by using `fping` or `ping` in a loop which returns once the return code of either of those functions is `0`, indicating a ping success.**

[As I put in my comment here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678045/equivalent-of-ping-o-on-linux#comment1280886_678045):

> after testing `fping`, I can say the following: `fping 192.168.0.1` behaves like `ping -c 4 -W 1 192.168.0.1` when the network is down, and like `ping -c 1 192.168.0.1` when the network is up. `fping` returns immediately if the network is up, and tries 4 times (1 initial try plus 3 retries, with a 1 second timeout after each attempt) if the network is down, returning after 4 timeouts = 4 sec total. `ping -o` would return immediately if the network is up, but loop forever *until the network comes up*, then return, if the network was down.

So, leveraging [the good work by @AlexPixel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678144/114401), here is my answer. This form catches the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> kill signal to allow you to forcefully exit the infinite `while` loop, it ensures you enter a parameter for the IP address when you run it, and it prints an attempt count and a message when the IP address comes alive.

**ping_loop.sh**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IP_ADDR="$1"
if [ -z $IP_ADDR ]; then
    echo "You must enter the IP Address as the first parameter!"
    exit 1
fi

# to enable Ctrl + C inside the infinite while loop
trap 'printf "%s\n" "Ctr + C"; exit 2' SIGINT
count=0
while true; do
    echo "Attempt: $count"
    ((count++))
    ping -c 1 -W 5 "$IP_ADDR"
    return_code=$?
    if [ $return_code -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "== DEVICE AT IP '$IP_ADDR' IS ALIVE! =="
        break;
    fi
done
```

Make executable with `chmod +x ping_loop.sh`. "Install" it like this:

1. Create a symlink in `~/bin` to this script so you can run it from anywhere:

   ```bash
   cd /path/to/here
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   ln -si "${PWD}/ping_loop.sh" ~/bin/gs_ping_loop
   ln -si "${PWD}/ping_loop.sh" ~/bin/ping_loop
   ```
2. Now you can use the `ping_loop` or `gs_ping_loop` command directly anywhere you like. This assumes `~/bin` is in your `PATH`. If using Ubuntu and this is the first time creating `~/bin`, you may need to log out and log back in for your `~/.profile` file to make this take effect because it will automatically add that dir to your path.

Test it with:

```
ping_loop 10.0.0.1
```

Now you can read this other answers here to see how to forcefully bring that IP address up and down for `ping` testing: [How to create Ethernet interface at a specific IP address that I can ping and force to sometimes reply and sometimes not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678162/how-to-create-ethernet-interface-at-a-specific-ip-address-that-i-can-ping-and-fo).

One approach is this:

```bash
# block traffic to 10.0.0.1
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -d 10.0.0.1 -j DROP

# allow traffic to 10.0.0.1 
# NB: you must run this as many times as you ran the cmd above in order to 
# allow traffic. So, if you ran the cmd above an unknown number of times,
# run this command as many times as it takes until you see:
#
#         iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
#
sudo iptables -D OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -d 10.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

Sample output. I started with the traffic blocked via the command above, and then unblocked it with the other command above to make `ping` pass and allow the script to end. You can see the `== DEVICE AT IP '10.0.0.1' IS ALIVE! ==` print at the end.

> ```
> $ gs_ping_loop 10.0.0.1
> Attempt: 0
> PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
>
> --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
> 1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
>
> Attempt: 1
> PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
>
> --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
> 1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
>
> Attempt: 2
> PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
>
> --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
> 1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
>
> Attempt: 3
> PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
>
> --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
> 1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
>
> Attempt: 4
> PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.20 ms
>
> --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
> 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
> rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.204/4.204/4.204/0.000 ms
> == DEVICE AT IP '10.0.0.1' IS ALIVE! ==
> ```

---

Here is my final form of **ping_loop.sh** in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/useful_scripts/ping_loop.sh <-- this is where I'll keep the latest and most-up-to-date version of this code!

### See also:

1. The 3 answers here, my own included, on how to turn an IP address's "pingability" on and off. This allows you to test the `ping_loop` script above: [How to create Ethernet interface at a specific IP address that I can ping and force to sometimes reply and sometimes not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678162/how-to-create-ethernet-interface-at-a-specific-ip-address-that-i-can-ping-and-fo)

Answer (score 5):

###### Using ping:

```bash
ping -c 1 ping_address
ping -c 1 192.168.1.68 #example
```

- `c` argument is for counting packets, so you need only `1` that's why --> `-c 1`
- After running a command, you can check its **exit status** by using the `$?` command. After using ping, you should see a **0** (success, OK). Otherwise, you get either `1` or `2` after typing `$?`, it means an **error**.

###### PING output returns with `echo`:

```bash
1 received, 0%   packet loss -> (Success echo $? #returns 0
0 received, 100% packet loss -> (Failure)echo $? #returns 1
```

##### An infinite loop that stops when the service becomes available, pipe it into a while loop.

```bash
while ! ping -c1 -W1 192.168.1.68; :;done
```

- While **NOT** `!` alive, keep looping and always exit with an exit status that **succeeds** `:`
- `-W1` is for waiting 1 second

copy this into a file with name `pingo`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
while ! ping -c1 -W1 "$1"; do
    : && echo "NOT ALIVE"
done
```

- `:` is a Null command or No effect, the command does nothing or exit status always succeeds, in this case, similar to typing true. Is a  [Bourne Shell Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)
- The variable `$1` represents the **first command-line argument**,  which in this case is a numeric **IP address**. For instance, `pingo 192.168.1.68` would substitute **$1** with the specified IP address."

###### bin directory for user

Create a folder with the name **bin**. Inside that folder, create a file with the name **pingo** and allow the file to be executed as a program.

```bash
mkdir ~/bin    # make directory at /home/user/bin
cd ~/bin       # change to /home/user/bin directory
touch pingo    # create file pingo copy the above command and save it
chmod +x pingo # give permission to execute
```

- the `/home/user/bin` folder is the default location for your own programs, which can be executed in the terminal from anywhere, just like the 'ping' command.

That's it, now you can run `pingo` with any address, just like `ping -o`.

###### From PING manual:

- If ping does **not** **receive** **any** reply **packets** at all, it will exit with **code 1**.
- If a packet **count** and **deadline** are both specified, and fewer than count packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived, it will also exit with **code 1**. On **other error**, it exits with **code 2.** Example:

  - count 1 and wait for 2 seconds **BUT** nothing has arrived at  second 2, **THEN** exit with error
- Otherwise, it exits with **code 0**. [ OK ]

*This makes it possible to use the **exit code** to see if a **host** is **alive** or **not**.*

Comment: Yes that was simple after all.

Comment: `ping -o` would return immediately if the network is up, but loop forever _until the network comes up_, then return, if the network was down. `ping -c 1` returns after a single ping regardless of whether or not the network is up, so it doesn't have similar behavior to `ping -o`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples infinite loop can be achieved in ping with `ping -W0 ping_address`, but to check if network is up or down, it's not going to work. It's going to be infinite out --> not network or when network  is UP will output --> `network working`, going to update answer, so you have `ping -o`

Comment: Would `while ! ping -c1 192.168.1.68; do sleep 1; done` be a little simpler? And a bit easier on the network.

Comment: Replace `sleep 1` with `:` if you don't want a delay in ping attempts.

Answer (score 4):

There can be various workarounds to try and make `ping` behave like Mac's `ping -o` but there's the command [`fping`](http://www.fping.org/) that does just that, and is intended to be used in scripts and for multiple targets at once. From [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/fping.8.html):

> [...]
>
> In the default mode, if a target replies, it is noted and removed from
> the list of targets to check; if a target does not respond within a
> certain time limit and/or retry limit it is designated as unreachable.
>
> [...]

Examples:

```bsh
$ time fping example.com
example.com is alive

real    0m0.074s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s
$ echo $?
0

$ fping 192.0.2.3 127.0.0.1
ICMP Host Unreachable from 203.0.113.1 for ICMP Echo sent to 192.0.2.3
127.0.0.1 is alive
ICMP Host Unreachable from 203.0.113.1 for ICMP Echo sent to 192.0.2.3
ICMP Host Unreachable from 203.0.113.1 for ICMP Echo sent to 192.0.2.3
192.0.2.3 is unreachable
$ echo $?
1
$ fping -q 192.0.2.3
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: It looks like `fping` is installable on Ubuntu with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install fping`.

Comment: Indeed the manual I linked is from Ubuntu.

Comment: `fping 192.168.0.1` behaves like `ping -c 4 -W 1 192.168.0.1` when the network is down, and like `ping -c 1 192.168.0.1` when the network is up.  `fping` returns immediately if the network is up, and tries 4 times (1 initial try plus 3 retries, with a 1 second timeout after each attempt) if the network is down, returning after 4 timeouts = 4 sec total. `ping -o` would return immediately if the network is up, but loop forever _until the network comes up_, then return, if the network was down.