# How to create Ethernet interface at a specific IP address that I can ping and force to sometimes reply and sometimes not?

Tags: ethernet, ping, virtual-interface

I'd like to do some experiments to test the `ping` and `fping` commands (see: [Equivalent of `ping -o` on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678045/equivalent-of-ping-o-on-linux)), but I need a local virtual Ethernet interface to test this.

I'd like to have a scenario where I can run `ping 10.0.0.1` (or any other IP) and have it fail. Then, while `ping` is still running, I run some commands that bring up the interface and have it pass. In other words, the output of `ping` will change *while it is running*, as the virtual device comes "alive". I don't want to have to use physical hardware.

How can I do this?

I've already tried following my own instructions here ([How can I create a virtual ethernet interface on a machine without a physical adapter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad/593142#593142)), but unfortunately even after running `sudo ip link set eth10 down`, pinging eth10 via `ping 10.0.0.1` still succeeds. After running `sudo ip link delete eth10 type dummy` to delete the dummy virtual device, `ping 10.0.0.1` also still succeeds.

---

### Summary of functional answers so far:

(as of 22 Nov. 2021)

3 answers received (my own included), and **all 3 answers work**!:

1. [by Stephen Harris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678208/114401) - use loopback sub-interfaces (probably the best answer so far)
2. [by Hauke Laging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678181/114401) - use iptables
3. [my own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678180/114401) - use virtual interfaces

Comment: Why don't you just use the firewall (`iptables` / `nft`) for sometimes allowing packets to reach their target and sometimes not? If this is only about `ping` and `fping` then that seems to be a lot easier than using virtual interfaces. Independent of that: There may be a different `10.0.0.1` somewhere. Compare the outputs of `ip route get 10.0.0.1` in both cases.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, thanks! I'd like to use `iptables` but don't yet know how. Can you provide an example command to block and unblock ping from reaching a given IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hauke Laging is right [in his comment under my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678162/how-to-create-ethernet-interface-at-a-specific-ip-address-that-i-can-ping-and-fo?noredirect=1#comment1280923_678162):

> There may be a different `10.0.0.1` somewhere. Compare the outputs of `ip route get 10.0.0.1` in both cases.

`ip route get 10.0.0.1` shows this *before* deleting the dummy interface:

> ```
> local 10.0.0.1 dev lo src 10.0.0.1 uid 46153590
> ```

...indicating that that route is going through the dummy interface I created, and it shows this *after* deleting the dummy interface by running `sudo ip link delete eth10 type dummy`:

> ```
> 10.0.0.1 dev wlp0s20f3 src 10.0.0.36 uid 28301632
> ```

...indicating that IP is now being routed through my `wlp0s20f3` wireless card. I guess that makes sense because my local WiFi is using and assigning `10.0.0.x` IP addresses.

The solution, therefore, is to simply choose a different IP which is *not* pingable before creating the virtual interface to it! Using `10.0.0.100` instead of `10.0.0.1` in my case worked just fine. But, let's just use `254.254.254.254` for the case of this example.

Full Example:

First, ensure the desired IP address you'd like to use is NOT currently responding to `ping`:

```bsh
ping -c 1 -W 1 254.254.254.254
```

Sample output:

> ```
> PING 254.254.254.254 (254.254.254.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
>
> --- 254.254.254.254 ping statistics ---
> 1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
> ```

Now create a dummy `eth99` interface (for a full explanation, see my other answer here: [How can I create a virtual ethernet interface on a machine without a physical adapter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152331/how-can-i-create-a-virtual-ethernet-interface-on-a-machine-without-a-physical-ad/593142#593142)):

```bsh
sudo modprobe dummy \
&& sudo ip link add eth99 type dummy \
&& sudo ip address change dev eth10 254.254.254.254 \
&& ip address
```

Now it IS pingable. Run `ping 254.254.254.254`. Sample cmd and output:

> ```
> $ ping 254.254.254.254
> PING 254.254.254.254 (254.254.254.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from 254.254.254.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
> 64 bytes from 254.254.254.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms
> 64 bytes from 254.254.254.254: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
> 64 bytes from 254.254.254.254: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
> ^C
> --- 254.254.254.254 ping statistics ---
> 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3050ms
> rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.051/0.079/0.093/0.016 ms
> ```

Now, if you run `ping 254.254.254.254` in one terminal, and `sudo ip link delete eth99 type dummy` in another, the ping response will quit incrementing once you delete the interface. `sudo modprobe dummy; sudo ip link add eth99 type dummy; sudo ip address change dev eth99 254.254.254.254; ip address` again will re-create the interface and make the ping start responding again.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you could do this with sub-interfaces on lo (loopback).

eg in one window I run

```
% ping 10.200.200.1
PING 10.200.200.1 (10.200.200.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

And I get no response, 'cos I don't have anything with that address.

In another window

```
% sudo ifconfig lo:100 10.200.200.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

And now the ping starts to responde

```
64 bytes from 10.200.200.1: icmp_seq=25 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 10.200.200.1: icmp_seq=26 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 10.200.200.1: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
64 bytes from 10.200.200.1: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
```

I can then do

```
% sudo ifconfig lo:100 down
```

and the ping stops working again.

Essentially all we're doing as adding a "sub-interface" to the loopback interface.  In this case I call it `lo:100` but you can pick `lo:1` -> `lo:255`.

Sub-interfaces are really just a way of assigning 2 or more addresses to the same interface.  For example if you assigned an address to `eth0:1` then your machine would have 2 address on the physical interface and other machines on your network could reach it on both.  Putting them on `lo` (loopback) means that only your test machine knows about the extra address and the rest of your network isn't impacted.

At a packet level any traffic for `lo:100` flows through `lo`.  This is different to *dummy* interfaces where a whole new interface is created and traffic is isolated.

Comment: Woah, that's pretty awesome! Upvoted. Best answer so far in my opinion, and *every* answer so far here works just fine. Can you update the answer to explain in detail exactly what's happening with these calls and in the computer with these commands and options? I'd like to understand both the commands and the actual communication path.

Comment: Brief description of sub-interfaces added.

Answer (score 1):

if you have added `10.0.0.1` to one of your interfaces then you can throw away ping packets to that address with

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -d 10.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

You can delete this rule with

```
iptables -D OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -d 10.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

By executing these two commands alternatingly you can switch between the two states.

Here is some sample `ping 10.0.0.1` output showing the packets going through, then getting blocked, then going through again:

> ```
> $ ping 10.0.0.1
> PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.04 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.20 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.33 ms
> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
> ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
> 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=8.49 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=3.33 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=6.90 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=6.91 ms
> ^C
> --- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
> 11 packets transmitted, 7 received, 36% packet loss, time 10088ms
> rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.330/5.459/8.491/1.859 ms
> ```

Comment: I had to use `sudo` for both commands. The error I got was: `iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table \`filter\`: Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.`